# Generating distinct random numbers efficiently

Tags: cryptography, steganography

My main purpose is to spread a buffer over pixels of an image randomly and efficiently, but I'm stuck at generating *distinct* random numbers. What I simply want is to generate numbers between **0** and **N**, but I also want these numbers to be distinct. Also note that **N** usually will be quite large such as 20 million and the algorithm doesn't have to be cryptographically secure.

I can't use random shuffle method since N is quite large. I did some search and found [Linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) but the parameter **m** is required to be prime, but my N is sometimes not.

Lastly, I tried the following approach but it's not quite efficient and reliable since it might throw *maximum call stack size exceeded* error.

```
next(max: number)
{
    let num = LCG.next()
    if (num <= max) return num
    return next(max)
}
```

Comment: You don't actually have any significant details in your question. Nothing about the language, or the parameters of your LCG, or why you think you'll get a stack size error, or why you are using recursion when a simple loop will suffice. However, using an LCG for the problem you have stated should be very efficient, as long the LCG modulus is less than 2*N. If, however, you need cryptographic quality security then an LCG will not be good enough.

Comment: I'm really sorry the discomfort, although it's not an valid excuse it's my very first question online, and I didn't think the language or the parameters is that important but most probably will put them next time. I did get _maximum call stack size error_ due to possibility of getting so many numbers bigger than **N** sequentially and I don't think there is a difference between loop and recursive function when converted to machine code but of course it also depends on the programming language that I didn't state which is JavaScript. Also, I don't need cryptographic quality security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If numbers are distinct, then they are not random.  Random numbers can repeat; distinct numbers are selected from an ever decreasing set.  It is the difference between selecting numbers with replacement and without replacement.

You want numbers from 0 to 20 million.  As you have found, that is too large for a shuffle.  Better to use an encryption.  Because an encryption is one-to-one, as long as you have distinct inputs you will get distinct outputs.  Just encrypt 0, 1, 2, 3, ... and you will get distinct outputs.

You talk about using a linear congruential PRNG so I assume that security is not of great importance.  20 million is about 2^24 or 2^26 so you can write a simple four round [Feistel cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feistel_cipher) sized appropriately to do the work.  Alternatively, use a standard library cipher with one of the [Format preserving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption) methods to keep the output within the bounds you want.

Comment: Great answer; it may be of use in looking for an algorithm that the general tool here is called a "pseudorandom permutation" (PRP), of which block ciphers are a subset that have stronger properties.

Comment: It's an awesome answer, and also sorry for not explicitly writing whether its cryptographically secure or not - just corrected it. However, thanks, really.